# Script to pulled element class inner html for Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript

I am working on a script that is meant to pull the inner html of a paragraph that is only shown onblur. I have spent hours on this and have not been able to successfully surface this inner html in our data layer.

Firstly, the data layer is custom (i.e. not the default data layer for GTM) - not sure if this makes a difference.

Secondly, the JavaScript I am using to attempt to achieve this. The onblur listener shows a parahraph (with no Element ID, only Element Class) when a user moves on from the form (which is the first parent element which has an ID, it is several parent elements up from the class). The paragraph passes a validation message (e.g. enter a valid email). I am attempting to pass the error message to the data layer:

```
<script>
object.onblur=function(){
var myForm = document.getElementById('instantSearchForm');
if(myForm) {
var myPara = myForm.getElementsByTagName('error-message');
if(myPara.length) {
var paraValue = myPara[0].innerHTML;
dataLayer.push({inputError: paraValue });
}
}}
</script>
```

Comment: myForm.getElementsByTagName('error-message'); are you using custom tags named error-message?

Comment: The class of the paragraph element that loads the error message is <p class="error-message active">Please enter a valid email address</p> so I am using 'error-message' here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment I see that you are using the class name for selecting your elements. Then you should try

```
myForm.getElementsByClassName('error-message');
```

instead of

```
myForm.getElementsByTagName('error-message');
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Strange how sometimes a person can get bogged down in everything that a person overlooks something simple. Thank you for your help Emilioicai